# Enable "Play" button for Undertale on Linux Steam

Tags: steam, linux, wine

I have downloaded the game "Undertale" on the Linux Steam client using [this method](https://github.com/dotfloat/steam-appmanifest).

However, Steam recognizes that the game does not run natively on Linux and will not allow me to start "Undertale" via a custom launch with Wine.

Is there a workaround that, for example, tricks the Linux Steam client into thinking that "Undertale" does run natively on Linux so that I can open "Undertale" through the Linux Steam client?

ALSO: I am currently using the Windows Steam client through Wine; I am writing this because I DO NOT want to use the Windows Steam client.

Comment: You've got this flagged as Wine.  Aren't you using the windows version of Steam inside Wine?

Comment: Linux and Windows are 2 different operating systems,.. you cant just "trick" a program, some things are coded differently depending on the OS.

Comment: Related questions; http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/is-it-possible-to-play-games-that-run-off-of-steam-on-a-linux-or-unix-based-os?rq=1 And http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/how-do-you-get-your-steam-games-to-run-on-ubuntu-through-wine-or-something-simil

Comment: @Vahx I meant like tricking the local client by editing a registry file or something to make it think that the game runs natively on Linux.  I want the "Play" button to be present is all.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I have Steam inside of wine, but I'm trying to get a Windows game that has downloaded properly on the Linux client to be started by Steam.

Comment: "Note: Steam will not run apps that don't have Linux support, but it will still download the data."

Comment: "Steam under wine"? Isn't there a native Linux binary for steam? Or do you need to load steam under wine to enable windows-based games? Can you add windows-based game to the native client as non-steam games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the time of me writing this answer, there are no ways to tell Steam to open Windows games using Wine. [Many people have asked, and want this feature](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/846940247967794537).

The only workaround to getting Windows games running in Linux (under Wine) is to run Steam itself inside of Wine. I can understand why this is problematic, but this is the way it was designed.

Additionally, Valve has [released a response](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1zkfmv/wearea_videogame_developer_aua/cfuh92b) as to why they ***won't*** be adding this in as a feature:

> WINE is definitely a useful tool for some things, but we're taking what we think is a more sustainable position by asking game developers to support Linux and SteamOS natively, for current and future titles. We think this is mostly what gamers want, too. It puts more power into the hands of developers and will result in better quality games in the end.

---

In short, there's nothing you can do beyond what you're already doing.

With the release of the Steam Machines, VR systems, and Vulkan, Linux gaming might finally begin to rise -- if we have the games. You can always try to contact developers of games and nicely ask for Linux support. If enough people show interest to justify the extra work, more developers might be willing to put the effort and energy into making Linux compatibility a thing (looking at you, Bethesda).